# Mouse cursor disaappears on keypress event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouse-cursor

I am using arrow keys to move an object in my code. Everything works fine except that the mouse cursor disappears when I press any of the arrow keys. How can I make the cursor stay visible? I am using this code check for arrow keys pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        checkKeys(event);
    }).keyup(function(event) {
        keyUp(event);
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's browser behavior (maybe even OS behavior!), you probably won't find a way to stop it with javascript.

It's intended to hide the cursor so you can see what you're typing. Try it on any website, keystrokes always make the mouse cursor go away.

Comment: Yes you are right. But the problem is that I need to have mouse cursor visible in my application. Just realized that this is Mac OS behavior. I guess that i will have to make a div to look like the mouse cursor.

Comment: Is the mouse cursor not coming back when you move it or something? I don't understand why this is a problem if your app works like every other webpage on the internet.

Comment: My web app involves painting and brush selection shortcut. Not every web page is just a page. ;)